# In image processing, why is it recommended to loop over Y first and then X second?

Tags: image, image-processing

I've read in a few places that when processing the pixels of an image, it is recommended that you loop over Y and then X pixels because it is more likely to be memory efficient. Why is this so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 
B1 B2 B3 B4 
C1 C2 C3 C4 
D1 D2 D3 D4
```

Supposing that's your image (and some sort of coordinates to it's points), it is stored in memory in a string, just like:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4.
```

Let's simulate those options:

For X and then by Y:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3 C3 D3 A4 B4 C4 D4
```

Now check on the string, how messy those access would be (just like random reads, right?)

Nor, For Y and then by X

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4
```

See? Straight forward read!

That's why.

Answer (score 4):

The pixels in the image are stored left to right first and then up to down.
Exactly like the letters in a book. 
It would be very tiring to read every letter in a page top to bottom first and thus slowly reconstruct the sentences.

**Don't work against the machine**
The reason it is faster, is because the CPU reads data into its cache in "left to right" order. Usually 8 or 16 bytes at a time into a `cache line`.
If you process that data in the same order it is far more efficient than if you scan data "top to bottom", the CPU will read a lot of data into the cache that will not get used before it is overwritten.

This will cause the CPU to have to reread the same data in the cache, wasting time.

**Speculative reads**
Also if you read left to right, the CPU can anticipate further reads and will get data into the cache pro-actively  trying to keep up with your reading. If you're following any other order it will declare your accesses as "random" and not bother.

Look up [`cache lines`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries) in wikipedia.

**Working *with* the cache is key**
Note that this 'rule' not only applies to images, but to all data in a computer.
[Cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss) are by far the biggest time eaters in most applications.